# Linq query to check list contains empty string then check for null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that may or may not contain an empty string. In the case that it does I want to create a linq query to check for nulls in a where clause while also checking for other values in the list and adding them to the where clause as well.

This is what I have now in linq format which doesn't check for null:

```
if (myList.Count > 0)
{
    objects = objects.Where(a => myList.Contains(a.Items));
}
```

This is the behavior I expect but wondering if theres a way to put this in linq format or a better way?

```
foreach(var listItem in myList)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listItem))
   {
       //This would only be hit once as myList has a distinct list of values
       objects = objects.Where(a => a.Items == null);
   }
   else
   {
       objects = objects.Where(a => a.Items == listItem);
   }
}
```

Comment: you better formulate your question in the way what do you want to achieve . From the code above it is not clear what do you exactly need.

Comment: @SergeyK The second piece of code is what I want to achieve. I am just asking is there a better way to do that

Comment: so what is the question then?? because I don't understand what do you else need. What result of filtering the collection of objects you need?

Comment: @SergeyK if there is an empty string in my list, i want the query to return rows with null values and any other string that is matched in the list

Comment: If list contains at least one null you want to select ALL objects?

Comment: @TheProgrammer in the code above is written something different you have for each null or empty string in myList you assign to objects = object with null items so if you will have many listItem that is empty or null you will repeat the same many times

Comment: @SalmanA if the list contains at least one empty string then I want to select all objects where Items = null

Comment: @SergeyK Sorry I forgot to specify in myList I am certain that an empty string would only appear once. It would be a distinct list of values

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write it like so:

```
objects = objects.Where(o => 
    myList.Any(l =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) ? o.items == null : o.items == l
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked best for me:

```
if (myList.Count > 0)
{
    if(myList.Contains(string.Empty))
    {
        objects = objects.Where(a => a.Items == null || myList.Contains(a.Items));
    }
    else
    {
        objects = objects.Where(a => a.Items != null && myList.Contains(a.Items));
    }
}
```